# MFC Assertion error when calling function from DLL

Tags: c++, dll, mfc

I am calling this functions from a DLL context,

```
void CmodguiApp::ReportStatusBarImageCount() {

CMainFrame *frm = nullptr;
auto app = AfxGetApp();
if (nullptr != app) {
     frm = (CMainFrame*)app->GetMainWnd();
}

assert(frm);

frm->setStatusBarImageCount(L"Text");

}
```

Everything is OK. `frm` is NOT a nullptr.

Then, inside `setStatusBarImageCount`, which is described below, the software causes an assertion error

What could be wrong?

```
void CMainFrame::setStatusBarImageCount(const wchar_t *str) {

     m_wndStatusBar.SetPaneText(m_wndStatusBar.CommandToIndex(ID_STATUSBAR_IMAGECOUNT), str);

}
```

This app has MFC dynamically linked. Please let me stress that the `setStatusBarImageCount` function is called from within a DLL, and not from the main MFC app.

[image: assertion error]

Comment: What exactly is the assertion error that occurs?

Comment: `CommandToIndex` probably returns -1. When you get debug assertion click "Retry" then click "Break" in the next window, it should take you to source of the problem.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it wont let me dig into the MFC code (only tells me it's on mfc120 dll)

Comment: @BarmakShemirani check the image update. It gives me that assertion error and wont let me dig into the MFC code

Comment: @BarmakShemirani the assertion is

Comment: Yes, sometimes it doesn't let you dig in. But at least it tells you the file name (but not the correct file path). Look for this file on your computer: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\wincore.cpp" (I am using VS 2015, yours might be in a different folder if you are using a different version). Then look at line 972 of "wincore.cpp".

Comment: @BarmakShemirani is this not related to me calling MFC functions outside an MFC extension dll?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani the assertion is at `void CWnd::AssertValid()`, more specifically at `ASSERT( (p = pMap->LookupPermanent(m_hWnd)) != NULL ||
     (p = pMap->LookupTemporary(m_hWnd)) != NULL);`

Comment: It's probably a multi-threading error as you had answered earlier. Though I am not sure what difference it makes where the call originates from. By the way, the debugger should take you directly to MFC source of error. Check if you have "Debug Source Files" in Solution's property page. See image: http://www.ericmartel.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/donotlook.jpg but sometimes the debugger just doesn't want to cooperate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was because I was calling the MFC API from a custom thread (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/975t8ks0.aspx)

This shall be done using custom message implementations, which is thread safe (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k35k2bfs.aspx)